# Heroku PostgreSQL Database - inconsistent enties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

i'm working on a Ruby on rails project adopted by another developer. It's deployed on heroku, uses heroku postgreSQL.

When i run the project on my local rails server with the remote database, it works fine. But there is one problem: I would like to delete some entries. So I tried to connect via PostgreSQL-Console. But it seems like the PostgrqSQL-Console gives me another version of the database than the one who is used by the app.

For example, the latest user ID in the app is 540 and in the database displayed by the console only 500.

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are connecting to a different database remotely. How are you getting the ID? From the app? To get a console up: `heroku run console`

Comment: Hey, im quite sure that I use the right database. I use exactly the same connection settings for both the ruby app and pgadmin/console. Is it possible, that certain entities aren't provided by the database, but injected in ActiveRecord by e.g. testing files?

Comment: Did you try `heroku run console`? I don't run pgadmin so I can't help you there. The Heroku console gives me all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. The elastic search index wasn't synchronized. Thank you for your help anyway.